# How does main.m works in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiapplication

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
   [pool release];
   return retVal;
}
```

1. will UIApplicationMain() call will return only after completion of our application execution? 
   because i have next line [pool release]
2. how can i pass the command line argument in main()?
3. What are the possible int value that UIApplicationMain() will return and their state?

Answer (score 2):

> will UIApplicationMain() call will return only after completion of our application execution? because i have next line [pool release]

`UIApplicationMain()` will never return. The `[pool release]` and `return` are just for aesthetic balance.

> how can i pass the command line argument in main()?

The command line arguments are already there in `argv`. You can do what you like with them prior to `UIApplicationMain()`. If you mean "how do I access them outside of `main()`," see [NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is generally not very useful in iOS.

> What are the possible int value that UIApplicationMain() will return and their state?

There are none. See the [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: if UIApplicationMain() will never return, then why we are assigning the UIApplicationMain() function call to int variable?

Comment: Probably for historic reasons.  Or perhaps there is a private API that makes it return, and Apple wants the template to work for their own apps that use the private API.  Also, the `[pool release]` is required to prevent the static analyzer from complaining.